# How to transfer control between scripts?

Tags: expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn telnet 10.123.9.111 
expect login {send username\r} 
expect password {send password\r} 
----Here i want to execute commands----
----Commands are stored in an array in example.pl script----
----All variables are global in perl script----
----After executing these commands, control should again transfer to the called perl script----
```

How can i make it ? Is this the right way ? Or any better ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drive control from Perl. I would write the expect script dynamically from Perl, coding in the commands to run from the array. Then Perl can execute the expect script:

```
system "expect", "/tmp/newly_written_script.exp";
```

and continue process when expect returns.